# Does the master branch gets modified when I merge it into another branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Simple question:

I recently found out that you can merge your `master` into derived feature `branches` (to update your feature branch with the latest `master` changes).

By doing so, am I modifying the `master` in any way? Or is it completely unaltered by that operation?

Comment: Like I said under your previous question, you learn better by doing than by asking. How many basic Git questions do you plan on asking? Why do you expect to modify master if you merge master into another branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no", but this deserves more than a short answer.

You'll find that you and Git get along a lot better if you think in terms of *commits* instead of in terms of *branches*.  Well, more precisely, it's important to remember which branch is the *current branch*—or use `git status` and see if it says `on branch master` or `on branch develop` or whatever—but *after* that point, think in terms of commits.

Each branch name points to one (single) commit.  That commit is the *tip* commit of the branch, by definition.  The phrase *points to* here means that the branch name literally contains the raw hash ID of that one commit.  Each commit has its own unique hash ID: no other commit can ever have that hash ID.  That hash ID means *that* commit, now and forever.

The special name `HEAD` refers to a branch name.<sup>1</sup>  That is, `HEAD` remembers one branch name, and the one branch name remembers one commit.

When you do:

```
git checkout develop
```

(assuming it succeeds), Git puts you "on" your `develop`, by making `HEAD` remember the name `develop`.  Your current *commit* is now the one that `develop` names.

When you subsequently run:

```
git merge master
```

(assuming it succeeds), Git has done all the work of merging—whatever work that is, which can get complicated—and then perhaps made a new commit.<sup>2</sup>  If it *did* make a new commit, the *name* `develop` now identifies the new commit.  The name `master` still identifies the same commit that the name `master` identified all along.

Each commit, meanwhile, refers to some number of *parent* commits, by their hash IDs.  Most commits hold just one parent hash ID, so most commits point backwards to their one parent.  This series of backwards-pointing arrows forms a chain.  For instance, perhaps the name `master` holds hash ID `H`.  Meanwhile, the commit with hash ID `H` holds hash ID `G`, and commit `G` holds hash ID `F`, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

Git can go from the name, `master`, to commit `H`, then back to `G`, to `F`, and so on, backwards through the chain of commits.

No commit can *ever* change—not one bit—so once a commit exists and has some parents, that commit always keeps pointing backwards to those parents.  (You cannot change a commit.  At most, you can get Git to stop looking at a commit.  If neither you nor Git can *find* the commit, the commit eventually falls out of the repository and is garbage collected.)  Git mainly just keeps adding *new* commits to the chain.

So we start out with something like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

You `git checkout` develop to select commit `J`.  (Draw the word `HEAD` next to the name `develop`, so that you can remember that you're on `develop`.)

Now you run `git merge master` and Git fires up the merge machinery.  That does a lot of computing, to figure out the right merge result, and builds a new commit.  Since the new commit is a merge commit, it points back to `J` as usual, but *also* to `H`:

```
...--F--G-----H   <-- master
         \     \
          I--J--K
```

As a result of writing out merge commit `K`, Git writes its hash ID—whatever that really is—into the name to which `HEAD` is attached, and now `develop` points to commit `K`:

```
...--F--G-----H   <-- master
         \     \
          I--J--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commit `H` is not changed—it *can't* be—and the name `master` has not moved, so `master` is not affected.

---

<sup>1</sup>The name `HEAD` *can* contain a hash ID instead of a branch name.  In this case, Git says that you are in "detached HEAD" mode.  Updates—such as creation of new commits—just write the new commit hash ID into `HEAD` directly, so that `HEAD` continues to be detached.  Use `git checkout` with a branch name to re-attach `HEAD` to that branch name.

<sup>2</sup>In some cases, `git merge` doesn't actually do a merge at all, but rather does a *fast-forward* operation.  This occurs when there's no merge needed.  For instance, if you're on `master` and have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J  <-- dev
```

and ask to `git merge dev`, the changes that Git would have to combine, if it were to do a real merge, would be whatever changed from commit `H` to commit `H` ("what you changed" on `master`) with whatever changed from commit `H` to commit `J` ("what they changed" on `dev`).  But obviously what's in commit `H` is the same as what's in commit `H`.  There's no need to actually do any merging!  If you permit it, `git merge` will not bother to merge at all, and will just check out commit `J` directly *and* drag the name `master` forward to match, giving:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I--J  <-- dev, master (HEAD)
```

Note that this is for `git checkout master; git merge dev`, not the other way around.  Doing a `git checkout dev; git merge master` would get you an "already up to date" message with nothing else changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you modify **nothing** in master branch. You just take changes from it to your feature branch.
"master" is not a some sort of "special" branch. It's just a normal branch with the same rules. And It's widespreading is because every new git repository starts with one branch named "master"